# Using chart.js in .jspx files

Tags: chart.js, jspx

I want to put a line graph on a webpage using .jspx files. I was advised to use chart.js which I installed with NPM but now what should I do to use it in my .jspx script ?

The integration code on Chart.js documentation doesn't seem to work in jspx.

Thanks